# show static image based on users in golang gin

Tags: go, routes, go-gin

I'm using the Gin framework. I have a database that contains some course info. Users can register in the courses and access the contents. The contents are image, video, and audio.
I store the relative location of these contents in my database like this:

```
Content\Courses\CourseOne\Unit_1\image\1.jpg
```

and change it to the actual location in gin:

```
route := gin.Default()
route.Static("/Content","./Media")
```

Everything works fine, but I am looking for a way to authenticate users before accessing the contents. In the above-mentioned way, all users can access any data by changing the desired pattern's address. But I want if the user is registered in the course, be able to access data, otherwise, get a 404 error.
how can I do that?

**Edit**

since it was asked to explain the implementation of authentication:

I used JWT for authentication. so each user has a HashID.
I have a table called UserCourses and the user info would be inserted after purchasing a course.

this is my course route:

```
route.GET("api/v1/courses", handler.GetCourses)
```

and my handler:

```
func GetCourses(context *gin.Context) {
    hashID, status, err := repository.GetToken(context)
    if err != nil {
        context.IndentedJSON(status, err)
        return
    }
    courses := make([]model.CourseAPI, 0)
    userInfo := model.Users{HashID: hashID}
    err = repository.DatabaseInstance.GetCourses(&courses, &userInfo)
    if err != nil {
        context.IndentedJSON(http.StatusServiceUnavailable, err)
        return
    }
    context.IndentedJSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"courses": courses})
}
```

The JWT token is passed by the client in the header. so I get the token and validate it. The token contains the user HashID and I check for that HashID in the UserCourses table. besides the course info, there is a variable called `isRegistered`.if the HashID was registered for any course in UserCourses table,the `isRegistered` become `true` for that course otherwise `false`.

Comment: You want the user to be logged in and be registered for a given course. You need authentication and authorization. This is a much more complex topic than can be answered in a single answer. I recommend you do some research.

Comment: @Marc thanks for your response. the other parts like authentication, ... are implemented. my problem is just handling the images. is there any to create a handler for the static route? in that case, I can handle the content based on user authentication.

Comment: How have you implemented authentication for the other parts... let say pages? Can you share that code?

Comment: I edited my question and added some explanations about the implementation of authentication. @Chetan

Comment: at the moment anyone can access any content. because the router, I mean `route.Static("/Content","./Media")` just change the relative address to the absolute one. I want to just authenticated users be able to access the contents. the authentication is based on jwt token as explained in question.@blackgreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create group route and apply authentication middleware through it

```golang
r = gin.Default()

// public routes
r.GET("public", publicHandler)

// routes group
auth = r.Group("/")
// authentication middleware within group
auth.Use(AuthMiddleware())
// route before which auth middleware will be run
auth.Static("/Content","./Media")
```